# Can I use Windows 8's File History to back up to two drives?

Tags: windows-8, file-history

Something isn't backed up until it exists in three places. I back up my laptop to two separate USB drives at work and at home (using the free Crash Plan client).

Can File History do this?

I can't determine this from Google searches, although most claim that File History is an improvement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself was looking into this. The easiest way I found was externally backing up the 2nd drive itself using 3rd party software. But when I was setting this up, I did not find any option to back it up to 2 different network locations/drives.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it makes sense to limit complexity for a default application.