# Can I have multiple backups in Windows 10?

Tags: backup, windows-10, file-history

I have File History set up to backup to a network drive. However, I would also like to do periodical backups to an external USB drive, possibly with a different set of files.

Does Windows 10 support having different File History jobs?

Comment: Windows 10 will track multiple revisions of a given file.  How many depends on how much storage you dedicate to that functionality.

Comment: But can I have say Folder A going to my network drive and Folder A + Folder B going to my USB drive?

Comment: Your comment does not make sense. All I indicated was that each file is tracked separately and has its own revision.

Comment: OK, but my original question was about having two different backup locations (one one a network drive and one on a USB drive). It doesn't seem to be possible?

Comment: The files in each location would be independent from one another.

Comment: Sorry, maybe location was the wrong word to use... what I meant was backup target. Can I have more than one backup target?

Comment: [interesting read](http://superuser.com/questions/500028/can-i-use-windows-8s-file-history-to-back-up-to-two-drives?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I'll need to look at alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Windows 10 support having different File History jobs?

AFAIK no.

You have two options:

1. When you connect USB drive, temporarily switch history destination, let it make backup, then set history destination back to normal location.
   When you select USB drive, it will offer to continue existing history to avoid making full copy. Same when selecting normal location.
2. Create another user account, let it access your account, and set up history there to backup your normal account to USB drive. Then, when you want to backup to USB drive, log in under that account and let history make the backup (it should happen automatically, but you also could click "Run now" in control panel).